# Get joined reulst from 2 table and when value not exist any of them, fill with empty value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables `clients` and `partners`

Table `clients`

```
company_id | name
------------------
11         | UA prods. 
12         | CI corp.
13         | UAC
```

Table `partners`

```
company_id | name
------------------
11         | UA prods. 
12         | CI corp.
20         | BDP Group
30         | UFF
```

I need get all company names from both table. When company exists in both tables, then theyr names, when doesn't exist, just leave it empty.

I tried left joins, inner joins but it gives me not what I want.

I want result like this

```
clients    | partners
--------------------
UA prods.  | UA prods.
CI corp.   | CI corp.
UAC        | 
           | BDP Group
           | UFF
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
(select clients.name as clients, partners.name as partners from clients
LEFT JOIN partners
ON clients.company_id = partners.company_id)
UNION  ALL
(select clients.name as clients, partners.name as partners from partners 
LEFT JOIN clients
ON clients.company_id = partners.company_id
WHERE clients.company_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: You're Welcome )

Comment: @OtoShavadze you should use union instead of union all that will speed up query and get result fast

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal  What if OP have 2 rows for example in `clients`  table with values (11, 'UA prods.') and OP wants get both of those rows?

Comment: @SunnyBatabyal Please don't try to update. this query not gives unnecessary duplicates, as you said in your edit attempt

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a FULL OUTER JOIN which is not supported by MySQL. But You can use a LEFT JOIN and a RIGHT JOIN, and an UNION ALL query instead:

```
select c.name as clients, p.name as partners
from
  clients c left join partners p
  on c.company_id = p.company_id

union all

select c.name as clients, p.name as partners
from
  clients c right join partners p
  on c.company_id = p.company_id
where
  c.company_id is null
```

The first query uses a LEFT JOIN will return all clients, and all partners whenever there's a match (or null instead).

The second RIGHT JOIN query will return all partners that don't have a match on the clients table.

Answer (score 0):

you will get this with the combination of two joins with the help of union like below

```
SELECT t1.c_name,t2.p_name
FROM clients t1
LEFT JOIN partners t2 ON t1.c_id = t2.p_id 

UNION 

SELECT t4.c_name,t3.p_name
FROM partners t3
LEFT JOIN clients t4 ON t3.p_id = t4.c_id
where t4.c_name is null
```

let me know if you got any issue...

Answer (score -1):

So basically the best solution to what you are looking for is `FULL OUTER JOIN` which is not supported by MySQL.

So in mysql you can do the same thing by this query -

```
SELECT clients.name AS clients, partners.name AS partners FROM clients
LEFT JOIN partners ON clients.company_id = partners.company_id
UNION
SELECT clients.name AS clients, partners.name AS partners FROM clients
RIGHT JOIN partners ON clients.company_id = partners.company_id
```

**NOTE : Don't use `UNION ALL`, it will give you a result like this -**

```
       clients    |  partners
-----------------------------------
       UA prods.  |  UA prods.
       CI corp.   |  CI corp.
       UAC        |  NULL
       UA prods.  |  UA prods.
       CI corp.   |  CI corp.
       NULL       |  BDP Group
       NULL       |  UFF
```